# same object multiple teams

Tags: deployment, metadata, package, git

I have a standard object , that is being used by multiple teams . Team A creates some custom fields on it and Team B also creates some fields on the same object . Currently these two teams have separate Git repos , since these two teams works on different business units and develop different functionalities , how do we make sure , we don't really overwrite or omit metadata changes done by each of the team doesn't get deployed , during deployments to production ? do we need Packages /unlocked packages etc not able to get onto a clean right approach , pls help thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the team's work is truly independent then the separate namespaces would be a benefit as collisions would be avoided because of the namespace prefix:

```
teama__NewField__c
teamb__NewField__c
```

But it might be that the right solution is to have a single `NewField__c` that both teams share. And packages add awkwardness in the process and limit your future choices in some ways.

Is your problem theoretical or actual? Simpler solutions such as introducing naming prefixes (rather than package namespaces) may be enough. And the teams should co-operate on building out the shared data model.

Comment: thanks for your comment ,but let me put my concern in detail, two teams share same org and same object - also the git repos are different , so if team A adds field x to contact object and pushes code to prod and then team B adds field y to same object pushes code to same object , we want to track those metadata changes , so that at any given point in time , while we are working on object we have both team fields ,so that we dont overwrite and omit changes of ecah other and push them to prod - and not namespaces for sure , they cause lot of trouble if not ISV

Comment: Hi@user2945545, If the collisions are always in the data model, a 3rd repository containing only the data model might help.